# XmlJavaTypeAdapter XmlElement not working for multiple fields

Tags: java, xml, java-8, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have one xml like below, I need to use this xml to populate the object below
I need the date to be in desired format and timestamp conversion of the date. I did that using the below mentioned code.

```
<customer>
    <name>john</name>
    <date>10/10/18</date>
<customer>

@XmlRootElement(name="customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private String name;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter (DateSort.class)
    @XmlElement(name="date")
    private String date;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter (TimeStampSort.class)
    @XmlElement(name="date")
    private long dateTimestamp;

    setters()/getters()
}

public class DateSort extends XmlAdapter<String, String> implements DateFormats {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String date) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String date) throws ParseException {
        Date pubDate = sourceDateFormat.parse(date);
        return outputDateFormat.format(pubDate);
    }
}

public class TimeStampSort extends XmlAdapter<String, Long> implements DateFormats {

    @Override
    public Long unmarshal(String date) throws Exception {
        Date newDate = sourceDateFormat.parse(date);
        return Long.parseLong(monthFormat.format(newDate));
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Long date) throws Exception {
        return new Date(date).toString ();
    }
}
```

The issue that I am facing here is the XmlJavaTypeAdapter is being called for "date" but not for dateTimestamp attribute. I am not sure why this behaviour exist.

I tried doing this configurations

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter (value=DateSort.class, type=Long.class)
@XmlElement(name="PUBDATE", type=Long.class)


@XmlJavaTypeAdapter (value=DateSort.class, type=long.class)
@XmlElement(name="PUBDATE", type=long.class)
```

and converting type to

```
private Long timeStamp;
```

None of this worked.

The problems here is I need the same element to be mapped to multiple pojo fields with conversions.
Are there any extra annotations that needs to be added to achieve this ?

Please help me fix the issue as in why TimeStampSort Adapter is not being called where as DateSort  gets called and works fine.

Comment: I already refereed those None of them seems to work

Comment: The issue is, I guess, that you can't map the `date` XML element twice. How does your `Customer` POJO look like? Couldn't you do it e.g. in the setter of the String date field?

Comment: Hi philonous,  Thanks for the reply, That's was the confirmation I needed, weather we can use element twice, I have provided the sample of my pojo, It consists of name,date, timeStampdate  attributes and setters and getters

Comment: @Flown Can you please remove the duplicate tag that ways multiple people could look into this

Comment: I think you shouldn't try and do transformations of your data structure(s) in the process of (un-)marshalling. Consider creating classes that map 1:1 to XML and implement conversion logic to translate instances of those classes to your 'business objects' (POJOs).

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks for the feed back I will consider implementing in that fashion. Right now I am curious to know why doesn't this code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example of how you can achieve what you are asking for.

It would be better though to do this "further up", i.e. in a service when retrieving the unmarshalled values. Generally speaking, you try to avoid having too much logic in simple mapped objects.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Customer {

    private String name;

    private String date;

    private long dateTimestamp;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date; // You can do additional transformations here
        try {
            this.dateTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(date).getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Handle this appropriately ;-)
        }
    }

    public long getDateTimestamp() {
        return dateTimestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Customer.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("name='" + name + "'")
                .add("date='" + date + "'")
                .add("dateTimestamp=" + dateTimestamp)
                .toString();
    }

}

public class XmlUnmarshaller {

    private static final String XML_STRING =
            "<customer>\n" +
            "    <name>john</name>\n" +
            "    <date>10/10/18</date>\n" +
            "</customer>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML_STRING.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        System.out.println(customer);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: The above way is the way to go about it, But I am still looking for why the earlier code didn't work. In my opinion that should have worked.

Comment: Actually I don't think so. I'm still wondering why it doesn't throw an exception if there are two `@XmlElement(name = "date")` annotations (having the same name!). Because which one should it pick when it encounters `<date>...</date>` tags? I have no clue about the actual implementation but I would guess it just uses the first one that matches ...